# Google and Firebase dependencies not resolving after Android Studio update

Tags: firebase, gradle, android-studio-2.3

I recently updated Android studio from 2.1 to 2.3.3 on Ubuntu 17.04. Additionally, I had to update my android.support dependencies from version 25.0.0 to 26.0.1 and my firebase dependencies from 9.6.1 to 11.2.0. I have tried everything on SO to no avail, including completely re-imaging ubuntu. All google/firebase dependencies still fail to resolve so It must be an error on my side. Below are my gradle files.

## Module build.gradle

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 26
    buildToolsVersion "26.0.1"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "me.myapp.app"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 26
        versionCode 10
        versionName "0.10.1"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            shrinkResources true
            minifyEnabled true
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'),
  'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'

    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.0.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:26.0.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:26.0.1'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:11.2.0'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:11.2.0'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:11.2.0'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-crash:11.2.0'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-storage:11.2.0'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:11.2.0'
    compile 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:[4,5)'
    compile 'com.github.amlcurran.showcaseview:library:5.4.3'
}




apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

## Project build.gradle

```
    buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.3.3'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.1.0'

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

Comment: https://firebase.googleblog.com/2017/08/some-updates-to-apps-using-google-play.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try to add

```
maven {
            url "https://maven.google.com"
        }
```

after **jcenter()** like below

```
allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        maven {
            url "https://maven.google.com"
        }
    }
}
```